# Use django model class into TypedDict?

Tags: python, django, python-typing

I am creating an API that takes the fields of a model.
Say

```py
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(blank=True)
```

I want to make an API that takes argument something like this.

```py
from typing import Optional, TypedDict
from models import Student
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict


class StudentInfo(TypedDict):
    name: str
    age: int
    address: Optional[str]

def createStudent(req:StudentInfo) -> StudentInfo:
    data = Student.objects.create(name=req.name, age=req.age, address=req.address)
    return {"data": model_to_dict(data)}
```

The above code will work fine, but there I have to define the same type for **Student** which I have already defined in the model.
**Can I use the model definition as the param type annotation instead of defining it again**?

Comment: Your `Student` model has no fields, since you use a colon (`:`) instead of an equal sign `=`.

Comment: Please check again.

Comment: Use the [DRF model serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

Comment: @JagjeetSingh Didn't work. Serializer actually serializes the data, but what I want here is the type.

Answer (score 0):

tried something like this?

```
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
    
def createStudent() -> QuerySet[StudentModel]:
    return MyModel.objects.all()
```

Comment: What you're returning is the array of model instances, but I have to return JSON type.

And QuerySet[ModelName] not returning the fields with types.